# How to get the value to enter a gtk.entry field and use it outside the button signal

Tags: python, gtk, signals, gtk3, slots

I use Python3.6 with gi.repository. Indeed I have created a Gtk.Entry that the user must fill in. This field is followed by a button. I would like to recover the value of the Gtk.Entry when the user clicks on the button. For my part I have created a signal, and when the user clicks on the button, I get the text from the Gtk.entry. however I would like to use this value in the rest of the code and not only in the function of the signal. please give me the right approach to do what I want.
here is my signal

```
# definition du signal pour entrer
def on_button1_nombre_mise(self, widget):
    nombre = 0
    try:
        nombre = int(self.entry.get_text())
        self.label.set_text("Tapez maintenant le montant de votre mise : ")
    except ValueError:
        self.label.set_text("Vous n'avez pas saisi de nombre")
        print("Vous n'avez pas saisi de nombre")
    if nombre < 0 or nombre > 49:
        self.label.set_text("Votre n'est pas compris entre 0 et 49.")
    else:
        self.input = nombre
```

Answer (score 0):

You're already saving it in an object when doing `self.input = nombre`. To use it somewhere else, just use access that object's `input` attribute, like in `thatobject.input` or `self.input`, dependng where is the code you execute.